# Is it possible to send two hashes to url and get both values separately with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I use a plugin for my portfolio page which uses hash to sort/filter items. also, I need to send a class name to url with hash. can I get the two hash values with jquery? if this is not possible, what is alternative solution to send the class name to url? (I don't want to set cookies)

Comment: use query parameters, if your using PHP at back-end then something like `http://domain.com?cssClass[]=class1&cssClass[]=class2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am explaining the basic logic of inserting and extracting ahash values.

```
 $(location).attr('href') will give you the current url.
```

Then **append two hash values** using

```
 $(location).attr('hash','FirstHashValue');
 var RequiredClassName = 'NameYouWantToAppend';
 $(location).attr('hash','FirstHashValue'+'#'+RequiredClassName);
```

**Extract these values from Jquery**

```
 var hashes = $(location).attr('hash')
 hashes.split('#')
```

hashes array will contain all the # values and one extra empty hash value at the beginning.

I tried this. It works. But let me know if anything is wrong.